# Getting @media queries to work correctly with buttons

Tags: html, css, button, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to do a few things here:

1. make these buttons responsive to each screen size
2. to have the buttons shift down when the screen size gets to Mobile- 
   size and smaller (but keeping at least 4 buttons per row so I can add 
   more buttons later)
3. when the screen size gets to 768px or above, the rows of buttons shift 
   back to being wider with 8 buttons per row
4. using bootstrap 4 (but will use 3 if it's better for this)

I've been trying to get these working like this for a couple days now but I just can't seem to get the media queries right. This is for a photo gallery I'm building.

The code I wrote is below and here's a codepen of it - https://codepen.io/gradyhouston/pen/bKLbOO/

Thank you for any help!

**HTML**

```css
.img-responsive {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .page-head {
    font-size: 18px;
    /* margin-top: -20px; */
    padding: 0px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-gallery .vertical-buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* display: block; */
  }
}


/* @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    } */

.all-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.vertical-align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}

.vertical-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

.locations {
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  /* position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly; */
}

.button {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  width: 90px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #285e84;
  /*   background-color: transparent; */
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  /* letter-spacing: 2px; */
  /* margin-bottom: 30px */
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #363636;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #42928b;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="locations">
  <button type="button" class="button all-button is-checked" data- filter="">All</button>
  <div class="container-gallery">

    <div class="row vertical-align">
      <div class="col vertical-buttons xs4 s4  l12">
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".jekyll">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".st- 
    simons">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".monterey">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".blizzcon- 
    2014">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".timberline- 
    lodge">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".lake- 
    trillium">Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row vertical-align">
      <div class="col vertical-buttons xs4 s4 l12">
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".santa- 
    cruz">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".san- 
    francisco">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".muir">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".vancouver">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".willamette- 
    falls">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".arlington- 
    cemetery">Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row vertical-align">
      <div class="col vertical-buttons xs4 s4 l12">
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".edgewood">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".hwy- 
    1">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".filoli">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data- filter=".seattle">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".chihuly- 
    garden">Test</button>
        <button type="button" class="button" data-filter=".mount- 
    hood">Test</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the line 'flex-wrap: wrap`to the selector`.vertical-buttons`. Try this code.

```
.vertical-buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/andrewchar/pen/jKZEPB?editors=1100

I stripped out a lot of code to just show the example of how you can do this with just a couple of bootstrap classes using bootstrap 4.

Adding the class `row` as our parent element of the div wrapping our btn-wrap you'll see that it adds `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` to the element. So without even having the need to use media queries, `flex-wrap: wrap` will just stack the divs when it runs out of room.

More work would be needed when you get into really small screens like Iphone5 but this is just to demonstrate that flex box can do the heavy lifting for us while using bootstrap 4